# Java: get rid of if else by using generic type

Tags: java, generics

in my code, I've used many if-else statements. I've learned that if-else and switch statements are not an elegant way to code, is there a good way to refactor the following code?

Wall, Trap, Door and Floor are subclass of Tile

```
    public class Player{
    ...
        public void move(DIR dir) throws Exception {
            Position nextPos = checkMove(dir);
            Tile nextTile = TileManager.getTileType(nextPos.getSeq());
            if (nextTile instanceof Floor) {
                walk();
            } else if (nextTile instanceof Wall) {
                block();
            } else if (nextTile instanceof Trap) {
                trap();
            } else if (nextTile instanceof Door) {
                unlock();
            }
        }
        public void walk(){
            ...
        }
        public void block(){
            ...
        }
        public void trap(){
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

I've tried to solve this by using method overload

```
public void move1(DIR dir) throws Exception {
    Position nextPos = checkMove(dir);
    System.out.println(nextPos);
    Tile nextTile = TileManager.getTileType(nextPos.getSeq());
    moveTo(nextTile);
} 
public void moveTo(Floor next) throws Exception {
    walk();
}
public void moveTo(Wall next) throws Exception {
    block();
}
...
```

and there is a compilation error

> The method move1(Floor) in the type Player is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Tile)

I've read some post that suggest generic type might be a solution, but i dont know how to implement it.

Comment: Add a method `action()` in your `Tile` interface and implement the method in all classes. You can just call `Tile.action()`. Can be done without generics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've learned that if-else and switch statements are not an elegant way to code, is there a good way to refactor the following code?

One potential solution is to add an abstract method to `Tile`, let's call it `action()`. (Feel free to come up with a better name.) Then you can do `nextTile.action()` without the `if` statement. Then rename `Floor.walk()` to `Floor.action()` and similarly with the other specialized methods for each `Tile` subclass. This has the added benefit that you can create new `Tile` subclasses and `move()` will be able to handle them without any changes.

Comment: Haah! You got here first :)

Comment: oh i did not make it clear, those methods inside of if-else statements are not methods from Tile and its subclasses.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, your solution is great. But what I wonder is, the code shared Eric Yu, I am not able to find any problem in that design. Though, it is true that having action() in subclass would help to call the appropriate method from move1().

Comment: @EricYu I see what you mean now that you make it more obvious in your edited code. My suggestion here requires moving the code from `Player.walk()` to `Floor.action()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the style depends on the language. You may mix Java and Kotlin in a single project:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html

You may create a Kotlin file in your existing Java project with something like this (not tested):

```
when (nextTile) {
   is Floor -> walk()
   is Wall -> block()
   is Trap -> Trap()
   is Door -> unlock()
   else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown expression")
}
```

Have a look at

https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Smart%20casts/Task.kt

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Comment: Plus 1 for Kotlin introduction.